What do you call the habit of using an example/thought process instead of a specific descriptive word?
I've noticed a tendency (including on the part of certain politicians!) these days to substitute specific words or vocab with a descriptive phrase or almost a stream of consciousness, I guess usually when the speaker can't come up with the right word.
An example could be,

But there's absolutely no doubt that they maintained a tradition of, this is where you put grandma.

In this example, instead of saying, "they maintained a burial tradition," the speaker used "a tradition of, this is where you put grandma."
Another example could be,

He has a mindset of, I'm going to come at you if you talk to me again.

instead of saying,

He's feeling defensive and wants to be left alone.

Any ideas what the term for his substitution might be?

It's not a new development. Sometimes you will find it with the words hyphenated:  He had this I'm-going-to-punch-you-in the-nose look on his face.

You're expressing by example.

Almost a duplicate, bar the hyphens, of Is a lengthy combination of words with hyphens like “the worst not-technically-in-a-recession year in American history” a new fashion of writing?. Compare we-find-each-other's-lame-jokes-funny vibe. Although there's not really a common name for it AFAIK.

It's also done with expressions in quotes e.g. a tradition of "this is where you put grandma" or a "this is where you put grandma" tradition. I can't find a question about that, but maybe I'm not searching correctly.

In many cass this is a way of avoiding using blunt terms that can be upsetting, so it's kind of like euphemism. Notice how the first example avoids using words related to death.

It's like the Amplified Bible approach to scripture: you don't need an extra commentary.

I may be overgeneralizing from the single example you give, but it seems to me that your complaint concerns the practice of speaking or writing in character, briefly, as someone other than oneself. That is indeed a trope, called  prosopopoeia. Like any trope it is a departure from the most direct and literal sort of discourse, but there is no call to sneer at it on that account: discourse without tropes, if possible at all, would be arid.
